# how to clear txt file when you exit your application c#

Tags: c#, file, exit

this is my code to fill my txt file, and show in my application.

```
StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("opslag_kentekens",true);
string opslag_kentekens = textBox1.Text;
file.WriteLine(opslag_kentekens);
file.Close();

label20.Text = File.ReadAllText("opslag_kentekens");
```

My question is: how do i clear my txt file when i exit my application?

Comment: What exactly problem you are trying to solve? Is it "how to empty text file" or is it "how to detect when I exit application"?

Comment: How do i empty txt file, when i exit my application the txt.file has to be cleared.

Comment: Again - it is two almost independent tasks - detect when application being closed and empty file. So what problem you are able to solve and what you are unable to do? Clearing file itself is pretty straightforward task. Detecting application exit depends on framework you're using - is it Winforms application, WPF one, console application and so on?

Comment: how do you currently exit the application? The code sample you've provided doesn't tell us anything about what your current problem is.

Comment: I exit my application just like normal with the red cross in the right corner.
My problem is i dont know how to clear my text file.

Comment: @greenfeet do you want to reward people every time they want you to google something for them?

Comment: Try to use FormClosing event.

Answer (score 1):

Clearing of text file is pretty straightforward: just write empty string into it:

```
StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("opslag_kentekens", false);
file.Write(String.Empty);
file.Close();
```

Catching application exit depends on framework you're using in your application.

For example, on WinForms (it looks like you're using it) you can override `OnFormClosed` method of your main application form and to your file clearing there:

```
protected override void OnFormClosed(FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnFormClosed(e);

    //clear your file
}
```

Or you can handle `Application.ApplicationExit` event and clear your file from there.